# UIDatePicker does not want to work on 32-bit iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit

I use `UIDatePicker` inside a view that works perfectly on 64-bit, but on 32-bit devices it does not seem to snap into different items (day, month, year), so that the `valueChanged` event is never broadcasted. Any ideas on this?

I use `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` limits if that helps.

Comment: See if this link helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181980/uidatepicker-bug-uicontroleventvaluechanged-after-hitting-minimum-internal

Comment: No sorry, this did not relate to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the cause of this was a high interval timer that I had on this view. This caused the scrolling on UIDatePicker and UITableView to be corrupted. Setting this to a higher interval solve it. Timer was at 0.01, now set to 0.1 interval.