# Date Picker with UIControlEvents.valueChanged doesn't work on the first value change event

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uicontrolevents

I'm using the code below to learn about Date Picker. It works, but the weird thing is the expected changes will not happen when I scroll the date picker for the first time. After that it will work normally. Wonder what happened.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Place this code inside your ViewController or where you want ;)

var txtField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // date picker setup
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    // choose the mode you want
    // other options are: DateAndTime, Time, CountDownTimer
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.countDownTimer

    // choose your locale or leave the default (system)
    //datePickerView.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDatePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    txtField.inputView = datePickerView

    // datepicker toolbar setup
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneDatePickerPressed))

    // if you remove the space element, the "done" button will be left aligned
    // you can add more items if you want
    toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    self.view.addSubview(txtField)
}

func doneDatePickerPressed(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func onDatePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let (h, m, _) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (duration: sender.countDownDuration)
    self.txtField.text = String("\(h) Hours  \(m) Minutes")
}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (duration : Double) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    let seconds:Int = Int(duration)
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your onDatePickerValueChanged function to see if it's being called?

Comment: I did, it's not, for the first change.

Comment: That's still a bug in iOS 10. Refer this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181980/uidatepicker-bug-uicontroleventvaluechanged-after-hitting-minimum-internal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange. This appears to be a bug in date pickers that are set to  `UIDatePickerMode.countDownTimer` mode.

You can get around *most* of the fail cases by implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` and setting the picker's value after a short delay. Here is the code from my test project. (In my project the time interval field is called `optionalTimeField`, and the time interval value is an optional called `optionalTime`. You'd need to change it to fit your code:

### EDIT:

See new function textField(_:,shouldChangeCharactersInRange:,replacementString:) below

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
  
   //Add this function to prevent keyboard editing
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
           shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
           replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       return false
  }

  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField === optionalTimeField {
      //Set the time interval of the date picker after a short delay
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.datePickerView.countDownDuration = self.optionalTime ?? 60
      }
      
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

I would suggest filing a bug report with Apple bug reporter. Based on the thread @Santosh linked, it looks like this bug has been in the `UIDatePicker` since iOS 7, which is bad.

One bug that I don't see a work-around for is that if you try to select a time interval of 0 hours, 0 minutes, it switches to 1 minute, and after that, the next time interval you select does not trigger the value changed method.

There are various strange things about the interval date picker, like the fact that you can't specify it to choose seconds. If it's important enough, you might want to create your own time interval picker based on a generic `UIPickerView`. It shouldn't be that hard. (Especially if you don't need to worry about localization to multiple locales that use different time formats.) You'd just create a picker view with spinners for hour, minute, and (optionally) seconds, populate it with your legal values, and away you'd go. You could set it up to have optional minimum and maximum interval values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try in short while. But now I have a new problem, I want my textfield only be edited by the date-picker's value change but not by direct typing the keyboard, may I ask how can I achieve that?

Comment: @CarolHan, see the edit to my code above. Add a `textField(_:,shouldChangeCharactersInRange:,replacementString:)` function that returns false to your `UITextFieldDelegate` extension